# How to apply arbitrary headers to static assets (public folder) with Thin webserver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, thin

I need to add CORS-related headers (e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`) to some or all (Thin server is not used in production, so security concerns can be dismissed) files in the public folder. Moving files into the asset pipeline instead is not an option (yet). How can I do that?

Comment: I checked Thin documentation, change log and Sinatra documentation. I think this is not possible. Alternative could be serving static files using e.g. Apache or nginx.

Comment: @AdamChwedyk yeah, I also came to this conclusion. I recall it only dimly by now, but I think in the end I just modified the Thin server source code, in the place where it initializes common headers. I think I started out by searching for the word "header" in the codebase.